# Change scale of raphael js path

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm trying to scale a raphael paper with multiple paths but it doesn't scale right.Some parts get smaller than others.
For example, if I try to scale the tiger example (http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html), the tiger doesn't scale right, only some parts of the tiger scale.

Thanks!

This is the code I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="tiger.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var r = Raphael(tiger).scale(0.5,0.5);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some example code to show what you're doing.

Comment: IS this with Raphael 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I'm using Raphael 2.x and I've just added the code I'm using. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Paper object doesn't have a scale method, so you'll have to loop through all of the objects on the paper in order to scale them.  I also found that scaling per object didn't work as well as using a transform:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var paper = Raphael(tiger);
  var tfm = 'S0.5,0.5,0,0';

  paper.forEach(function(obj){
   obj.transform(tfm);
  });
};
```

Comment: There is no need to iterate through all the shapes if those shapes are put in `Paper.set()` and then you change the set transformation, for example: `var set = paper.set([ myCircle, myRect, ...etc]); set.transform("t100 0");`

And, in order to "scale" a Paper object you could possibly use `Paper.setViewBox()` method.